# execute Boolean variable with "true" - only once with delay - then normaly

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Have a interesting question.
How can i execute

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+3, execute: {
var = true
}) - only once with this delay, than - normaly? (without delay?)
var = true
```

I ve tryed with lazy but it's not helps.... Maybe DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter have mpdificator or something?

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the delay based on the bool value of your variable:

```
    let delay = myVar == true ? 0.0 : 3.0
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay, execute: {
        myVar = true
    })
```